# Having trouble with specs for a Ruby mixin module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module

I don't have a great experience with mixin modules. Then, please forgive me if my question seems to be a bit naïve.

I am creating a few modules to integrate a project with music services like Spotify, who have REST APIs. All these modules include another mixin module I created named APIClientBuilder, which provides a small DSL for creating API endpoints.

**lib/integrations/api_client_builder.rb**

```
require 'rest-client'

module APIClientBuilder

  attr_accessor :api_client, :endpoint, :url, :param

  def api_client(api_name)
  end

  def fetch_client(api_name)
  end

  def api_endpoint(endpoint_name)
  end

  def fetch_endpoint(api_name,endpoint_name)
  end 

  def method=(meth)
  end   

  def url=(endpoint_url) 
  end

  def param(param_name,param_value)
  end

  def call(api_name,api_endpoint,token,*extra_params)
  end

end
```

**lib/integrations/spotify.rb**

```
require_relative 'api_client_builder'

module SpotifyIntegration

  include APIClientBuilder

  def base_url
    'https://api.spotify.com/v1'
  end

  def random_state_string
    (0..10).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
  end

  api_client('spotify') do |apic|

    apic.api_endpoint('request_authorization') do |ep|
      ep.method = :get
      ep.url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
      ep.param("client_id",SPOTIFY_KEY)
      ep.param("response_type","code")
      ep.param("redirect_uri","http://localhost:3000")
    end

    apic.api_endpoint('my_playlists') do |ep|
      ep.method = :get
      ep.url = "#{base_url}/me/playlists"
    end

  end

end
```

My idea was having in my controllers something like this:

**app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb**

```
require 'integrations/spotify.rb'

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  include SpotifyIntegration

end
```

And then have access to the methods in `SpotifyIntegration` and, through this, to the methods in `APIClientBuilder`.

It happens that I wrote the following spec file with a very simple test:

**spec/lib/integrations/spotify_integration_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

require 'integrations/spotify'

class SpotifyClientTester
  include SpotifyIntegration
end

RSpec.describe SpotifyIntegration do

  context 'Auxiliary methods' do

    it 'Two calls to random_state_string shall generate two different strings' do
      obj = SpotifyClientTester.new
      s1 = obj.random_state_string
      s2 = obj.random_state_string
      expect(s1).not_to eq(s2)
    end

  end

end
```

But when I run it I get

> undefined local variable or method `base_url` for SpotifyIntegration:Module (NameError)

I am not sure about what I am missing. Maybe I should use `extend` instead  of `include`. I always make some confusion about this.

Can someone put me in the right path? I've been fighting this error for a whole afternoon.

Comment: Which line is it failing on? You are not even calling `base_url` method in the test and `random_state_string` doesn't call `base_url`.

Comment: `lib/integrations/spotify.rb:33`, which says `ep.url = "#{base_url}/me/playlists"`. You mentioned exactly what confuses me most. I don't even call `base_url`.

Comment: This is not in the snippet in this post, `ep.url = "#{base_url}/me/playlists"`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now. I had mistakenly removed this part.

Comment: Is there a reason that this is at class level?   api_client('spotify') do |apic|
----------
  end

Comment: Yes, there is. This is the creation of the API client endpoints which will be used in all the rest of the controller. This is the initialization of the API client I am creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing mixins. Use mixins for cases where classical inheritance is not suited to add a set of features to objects.

For example:

```
module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  end 
  # ...
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  include Commentable
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  include Commentable
end
```

As you can see by this example you `extend` a module with other modules and `include` modules in classes. Using classical inheritance to add the shared behaviour would be awkward at best since the two classes are apples and pears.

In your specific case you should instead use classical inheritance and not mix the API client into the controller. Rather you controller should invoke it as a distinct object.

```
class APIClient
  # Implement shared behavior for a REST api client
end

class SpotifyClient < APIClient
  # ...
end 

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    client = SpotifyClient.new
    @foos = client.get_something
  end
end
```

Why shouldn't you mix a API client into a controller or model? Because of the Single Responsibility Principle and the fact that using smaller parts that do a limited amount of things is preferable to creating god classes.

Comment: Yes a client could be a module if you don't intend to create instances of it. But in most cases you want setup clients and service objects as classes to make it easier to inject configuration through the initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `APIClientBuilder` if you want to use the methods defined here at class level in module `SpotifyIntegration`.

```
module SpotifyIntegration

  extend APIClientBuilder
```

Also, `base_url` must be a class method too, `def self.base_url`

Comment: Extend it in `SpotifyIntegration`?